# Which is the native method used to get the external links in mupdf library?

Tags: android, hyperlink, mupdf

I tried [customizable magazine app, using muPDF:](https://github.com/libreliodev/android) code for reading a pdf. Internal links are working but external links are not working. What should i do to correct this. Anyone know which is the native method used for external links similar to the following

```
private native LinkInfo [] getPageLinksInternal(int page);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think getPageLinksInternal returns all links - internal and external. The "internal" in the method name is because it is called by getPageLinks:

https://github.com/libreliodev/android/blob/master/src/com/artifex/mupdf/MuPDFCore.java#L480

You can iterate through the array of LinkInfo you get and check for "instanceof LinkInfoExternal" to find the external links.

Example here:

https://github.com/libreliodev/android/blob/master/src/com/librelio/lib/utils/PDFParser.java#L42